# including command line arguments in window title

Tags: fish

My current fish_title function is as follows:

```
# Set the window title                                                           
function fish_title                                                              
    if [ $_ != fish ]                                                            
        echo (prompt_pwd)": $_"                                                  
    else                                                                         
        echo (prompt_pwd)":"                                                     
    end                                                                          
end
```

It puts an abbreviated version of the current working directory and the currently running command in the window's title bar. However, what I need is to put both the base command and its arguments in the window title. For example, if I run

```
ssh home
```

currently I see "~: ssh" in the window title. I need "~: ssh home". This is because I use a [password entry program](http://www.nurdletech.com/linux-utilities/abraxas/index.html) that triggers off the window title and the password must match the ssh destination.

Is there a way to include the command line options in the window title from fish shell?

Answer (score 1):

I requested this in fish [back in 2012](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/334), but it's finally been [added in development versions](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/1554) as `$argv`.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching your desired goal from a different angle, you could do as I have done and explicitly include the remote hostname in your title. I already extract and use the hostname in [my fish prompt](https://github.com/justinmayer/tackle/blob/master/themes/entropy/fish_prompt.fish#L6) via:

```
set -g __fish_prompt_hostname (hostname|cut -d . -f 1)
```

... so I re-use that `__fish_prompt_hostname` variable in [my fish title](https://github.com/justinmayer/tackle/blob/master/themes/entropy/fish_title.fish#L2-4) if, and only if, I'm currently connected to a remote host via SSH. You could do something similar, perhaps modifying your relevant line above to be:

```
if [ $SSH_CONNECTION ]
    echo (prompt_pwd)": $_ $__fish_prompt_hostname"
end
```

As an aside, I published the [Tacklebox](https://github.com/justinmayer/tacklebox) and [Tackle](https://github.com/justinmayer/tackle) projects in order to share these kinds of fish functions and tools, so feel free to check them out, see if anything there meets your needs, and/or contribute to the projects.